# How to fix "synce failed"

Tags: android-studio

My android studio worked fine but now I always have this message when I start it:

> C:\Users\GERA.gradle\caches\4.6\file-changes\last-build.bin (Access is denied)

Also my files tree looks diferent now and Java files are not blue anymore.
This is a Android studio level problem, not only one project.

How to fix that?

Comment: Remove `Cache` folder and try again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to File-> Invalidate caches / Restart
2. remove .gradle folder
3. Restart Android Studio
4. Gradle build succeed
5. Rebuild project